# List comprehension to add item to every list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists, and I want to add the same item to every list within the list of lists. I can do this with a for loop, but I'd like to know how to do it with a list comprehension.

```
ls = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 

for i in ls:
    i.insert(0, 'x')

ls
[['x',1,2,3],['x',4,5,6],['x',7,8,9]]
```

This doesn't work

```
ls = [[i.insert(0, 'x')] for i in ls]
```

I just get

```
[[None], [None], [None]]
```

Comment: You **don't** do it with a list comprehension - you want to change existing lists, not create new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `insert` is inplace (it modifies the list it is called upon and returns `None`).

You *could* do `[[i.insert(0, 'x')] for i in ls]` (without re-assigning it to `ls`) but the explicit loop has better readability and no "magic" side effects.

```
ls = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[i.insert(0, 'x')] for i in ls]
print(ls)
>> [['x', 1, 2, 3], ['x', 4, 5, 6], ['x', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for the explanation.  There was a fundamental gap in my understanding of insert.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `insert` you could simply add the lists:

```
ls = [['x'] + i for i in ls]
[['x', 1, 2, 3], ['x', 4, 5, 6], ['x', 7, 8, 9]]
```

as noted, `insert` alters the list *in-place* returning `None`; that's what you populate the list you're creating with.

In Python `>= 3.5` this can be prettified by unpacking in a list literal:

```
ls = [['x', *i] for i in ls]
```